# Como enviar correo electronico automaticamente con dias establecidos en pag web o programa

Tags: php, javascript, html, email, html-correo

he estado investigando como puedo enviar correos electronicos (recordatorios) a **X** cantidad de usuarios mediante un limite de tiempo, si tengo el conocimiento de como mandar correos y adjuntar archivos pero no el de mandarlos automaticamente por ejemplo:

Se registra un usuario el dia **28 de Octubre del 2019** y cada ciertos dias (10, 5, 3 dias) se le envié un correo para recordarle algo, enviarle un correo automaticamente.

Alguna recomendación de por donde empezar?

Tengo el registro del usuario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una tabla donde puedo generar un pdf
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Etiqueta el motor de base de datos y sistema operativo.

Comment: Para realizar tareas programadas debes utilizar algo llamado `Cron Job`, es una ejecución automática de un archivo (script) por parte del sistema operativo.

Para ayudarte más específicamente necesitamos saber sistema operativo del servidor, lenguaje del backend y si estás utilizando algún framework.